# How can I set a limit on how much disk space BlueJeans' logs take?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

How can I set a limit on how much disk space BlueJeans' logs take? Currently BlueJeans' logs are taking ~400MB on my disk (Windows 7).

[image]

Comment: In addition to compressing those logs as indicated in the current answer, since they appear to be date specific and if these are not something you need to retain long term, you could easily setup a daily batch script to purge logs from this location that are `x` days or older. Otherwise, I'd second that suggestion to simply enable compression on the folder and run with it if the app does not provide an option to keep `x` days, etc. only.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks, it's ok I'll write some script to empty the log folder at startup time.

Answer (score 3):

I havent used BlueJeans in ages, so I dont remember where/if you can set a log limit.

However, as a stopgap, you can always use Windows folder compression on the log directory.  That should significantly reduce the size of the logs on disk with no visible performance loss.  Typical log files are highly redundant and should compress very well.